# Windows Server 2003: Task Scheduler is not running successfully VBS file jobs

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2003

We have an old Windows Server 2003 r2 which is doing nothing but using the task scheduler and a VBS file to check and rename some regularly re-occurring data files.  It is setup to run every hour using my credentials.  If I "run" it while I'm logged on the task runs and completes correctly.  When no one is logged on the task runs but completes with an 0x1 code, ie it failed.
I have checked the event logs and see nothing which I can identify as an error or failure.  We believe that it was running successfully until about 6-8 months ago (yes, it was one of those set it up and forget it things and we have not been regularly checking it).

=================Additional Information===============

I ran ***assoc .vbs*** and got this output: ***.vbs=VBSFile***

I'm not sure how to determine the ***user environment variables***?

For the task I have tried both the vbs file and also a bat file containing the reference to the vbs file.  Both run when I'm logged and both fail to complete successfully when I'm not.

Here is the vbs script:

```
Dim fso, file, recentDate, recentFile, theFile, myfolder, mypath
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set recentFile = Nothing

mypath = "D:\TheFTP\Main\Camera\lobby" 

set myfolder = fso.GetFolder(mypath)
For Each file in myfolder.Files
  If (recentFile is Nothing) Then
    set recentFile = file
  ElseIf (file.DateLastModified > recentFile.DateLastModified) Then
    set recentFile = file
  End If
Next

fso.CopyFile mypath& "\" & recentFile.name, "D:\TheFTP\main\camera\cam3.jpg"
set recentFile = nothing
set fso = nothing
```

Here is the last bat file where I have piped the output to a file:

```
C:\windows\system32\cscript.exe c:\CopyWebCamFile.vbs > c:\debug.txt
```

Debug.txt output when I'm not logged on shows an error, see below, which is not there when I run it and am logged on:

**Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.6**

**Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1996-2001. All rights reserved.**

**CScript Error: Initialization of the Windows Script Host failed. (The system cannot find the file specified.**

=====================================================

More information, I added several ***Wscript.Echo*** statements to my script, before the first line, after the FOR loop and before the "***copyFile***" command.  When I'm logged on I see all of the output in C:\debug.txt.  When NOT logged on I see the same above error message, ie no ***Wscript.Echo*** output.  This would see to indicate that it can not find my vbs file when I'm not logged on.

===========================

Still no happiness here.  I moved and modified the .bat file to also output the contents of the script file:

```
type H:\Task_Stuff\CopyWebCamFileTest.vbs > H:\Task_Stuff\debug2.txt
C:\windows\system32\cscript.exe H:\Task_Stuff\CopyWebCamFileTest.vbs > H:\Task_Stuff\debug.txt
```

As before I get output to both .txt files when it runs while I'm logged on and nothing in debug2.txt and the usual messages in debug.txt when I'm not.

I'll fiddle with the antivirus settings, but I need to ask about that first.  We are using Symantec SEP.

How can I check on the ***user environment variables?***

====================

Maybe this will clarify my problem or suggest a solution??

Can you offer any ideas...RDK

Comment: Is the .vbs script dependent upon user environment variables?  If so, it probably won't work when "user is not logged-in".  Are you fully-qualifying the path to both C:\windows\system32\cscript.exe and your .vbs script in the task?  I've seen instances where a bad %PATH% and %PATHEXT% can cause problems like this.  Is cscript.exe or wscript.exe setup as the default handler for .vbs file extensions?  You can check using: ASSOC .vbs.  Could the scheduled task be using an old, cached password?  Editing the task and pressing [OK] should prompt you for your new password.  Hope something here helps.

Comment: I will update my question with results from  your suggestions

Comment: Can you try moving your .vbs script to a folder?  You might be encountering a restriction being enforced by your anti-virus security software or software restriction policies (eg, when running a .vbs from the root of drive C: by a scheduled task).  Curious: When was the last time the server was rebooted?  Just to ensure there's enough memory and handles available.

Comment: I have updated my question following your idea about moving the scripts to a folder and some other ideas

Comment: I don't see any dependency on user environment variables in your script, so you can ignore that comment.  However, are drives H: and D: local drives?  If not, ensure they are persistent drive mappings (between reboots) that are always available to the scheduled task account, and do not require a netlogon script to map them.

Answer (score 0):

First off we would like to thank ***LeeHarvey1*** for his time and suggestions as we searched for the cause of this issue.  In the end it was one of his suggestions that fixed the problem, but we still have no idea what caused it.

A reboot of the system cleared up all of the issues surrounding the task scheduler and running VB Scripts!  We had considered his early suggestion, but discounted it as this server had only been up for a little over 3 months.  Not excessive in our experience.  However, when all else failed we elected to do that and "voila" it fixed the issue.  We wish we knew what caused it but are now just happy we can move on to other things.

Thanks again ***LeeHarvey1***....